# Chained git remotes: dev repos -> repo on intranet -> repo on github

Tags: git, github, githooks

Developers within the firm all has access to a git repo on our intranet (network drive). I would like to set up a 'central' git repo on the intranet, from/to which all developers can pull/push commits.

I would like this intranet repo to be synchronized with a remote repo on github, with only one admin account (myself) having any access to the github repo. That is, I don't want to give ssh keys or username/passwords of our github account to our developers or their computers.

How can I achieve this given I have all the ultimate privileges within the firm?

```
dev1 <-\
        --> intranet repo --> github repo
dev2 <-/
```

Edit:

The solution I decided on:

- Use python watchdog on my machine with access to my ssh keys and ssh-agent, to monitor for changes to intranet repo.git/refs/heads/ folder (which should be sufficient given it is a bare repo), debounce it
- upon watchdog debounced trigger, use GitPython to do a git push to github

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to setup a server which will listen to push/pull and update your intranet repo.

Typically, I use a GitHub-like server: [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), because it is *one* executable (no dependencies) + 1 PostreSQL database.

From there, you can [setup a mirroring between your GItea and GitHub](https://jpmens.net/2019/04/15/i-mirror-my-github-repositories-to-gitea/).